# Замена отрицательных значении в определенном столбце на медианные значения

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Делаю так:

```
my_stat[my_stat.n_users < 0.0] = my_stat[(my_stat.n_users >= 0.0) & (my_stat.n_users != -0.0)].n_users.median()
```

так он меняет значения не только в одно столбце, а во всем датафрейме. Подскажите где ошибка

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка - в неправильном использовании индексирования и доступа к элементам DataFrame.

`df[boolean_mask]` - выберет те строки DF, в соотв. позиции которых элемент `boolean_mask` - истинный и при этом **все** столбцы DataFrame.

чтобы выбрать / изменить подмножество (строк / столбцов DataFrame) используют индексаторы (`accessors`) [`df.loc[]`,  `df.iloc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html):

```
my_stat.loc[my_stat["n_users"] < 0, "n_users"] = \
    my_stat.loc[my_stat["n_users"] >= 0, "n_users"].median()
```